# DSE Solr + CAS cluster "Index is down: null" on CAS nodes

Tags: solr, cassandra

I have been evaluating DSE3.0.1 specifically for its Solr capabilities. The idea behind this evaluation is to know if DSE can meet our requirements. The questions are below. It would be very helpful if someone can answer them. Thanks in advance.

1. I have 5 nodes; 3 CAS and 2 SOLR.
2. I don't generate tokens. I rely on auto token instead. so, I started CAS 1st node then Solr 1st node, then CAS 2nd node and then Solr 2nd node and then CAS 3rd node. I hope order won't matter here but I wrote it just to be specific.
3. I verify my cluster by /dse/bin/nodetool. Below is the output. (you can see I got 2 DCs)

   Address         DC          Rack        Status State   Load            Owns                Token                                                                                                154189492263095927406092457372548695412
   172.16.8.110    Cassandra   rack1       Up     Normal  26.36 KB        45.24%              61016887854694676542577351529976878246
   172.16.8.206    Solr        rack1       Up     Normal  21.16 KB        3.30%               66625824955492359989178535259749945160
   172.16.9.96     Solr        rack1       Up     Normal  21.12 KB        3.30%               72234762056290043435779718989523012075
   172.16.9.95     Cassandra   rack1       Up     Normal  30.79 KB        2.93%               77220913211027946537920259499236406851
   172.16.9.81     Cassandra   rack1       Up     Normal  45.99 KB        45.24%              154189492263095927406092457372548695412
4. I create a keyspace from cql.sh by below command:-

CREATE KEYSPACE sis WITH strategy_class = NetworkTopologyStrategy   AND strategy_options:Cassandra=2 AND strategy_options:Solr=2;

1. I create a CF with only primary key becuase I have to add columns dynamically.

   CREATE TABLE device ( KEY text PRIMARY KEY );
2. I push SolrConfig.xml on one of my Solr node.
3. I push Schema.xml on the same Solr node as above. My schema has dynamic fields.
4. I then create the Core.
5. I now insert data on cql.sh (a very simple insert statement) and I get below warning on all of my CAS nodes.

WARN [MutationStage:36] 2013-04-29 18:16:08,210 SolrSecondaryIndex.java (line 126) Index is down: null

Questions:-

1. Could anyone please let me know why my CAS nodes get this warning and how to resolve it?
2. Is it mandatory to have at least one concreate field (in addition to unique field) while using dynamicFields? Can't I have just one KEY (concreate field) and all others are dynamic?

Comment: you are working on which dse version?